# How can I trigger local Firestore Cloud Functions using the emulator?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I've just set up the Emulator per the instructions [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator):

```
Dan$ firebase emulators:start --only functions
Starting emulators: ["functions"]
✔  functions: Emulator started at http://localhost:5001
i  functions: Watching "/Users/danfein/Desktop/reviews/backend/functions" for Cloud Functions...
```

I understand there's something running at :5001. My local DB environment is not running locally (as I understand that's not something supported by Firebase) so because my connections are going out to the web, I don't understand how to trigger something to :5001.

How can I, with my running React instance (running on :3000 if relevant), trigger one of the cloud functions currently living in my functions folder.

The functions do currently run and are appropriately triggered in the cloud.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to set up your development environment as described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator).  There is a new emulator suite that ties together Cloud Firestore (which actually *can* be emulated) and Cloud Functions.

Comment: Hi Doug, so it sort of jumps right into commands. I'm just having trouble conceptualizing what interface I will be using once it's set up/how I will actually trigger the commands. If it's there, it's not obvious right now (to me). Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Did you click through to the quickstart example at the bottom?

Comment: Ah no didn't see that bit. Thank you for pointing me to it, will jump in